# Pointers C++ causing errors

Tags: c++

The function **ChangeArray** has an array, and in function **changeNelements** I want to use a pointer to modify the values in it. I am getting ***error C3861*** at *changeNelements(a,x,y);* at the end of function **ChangeArray**.

```
void ChangeArray(int a[],int asize)
{
int x,y;
do{
    cout<<"Enter X: ";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<endl;
}while(x<0 || x>=asize-1);

do{
    cout<<"Enter Y: ";
    cin>>y; 
    cout<<endl;
}while(y<0 || y>asize-1 || y<=x);

changeNelements(a,x,y);
}

void changeNelements(int *x,int n,int m)
{
for(int i=n+1;i<m;i++)
    *(x+i)+=(m-n);
}
```

Comment: You have to declare a function before calling it